# Unnecessary Stubbing in test class when writing unit test in junit using mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

A method already exists as part of a module in the project. I am trying to write a test case to improve coverage. The method and it's associated class is :

```
@Component
public class GenericRestTemplate {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    CtmLogger ctmLogger;

    public <R, T> R persistGenericModelsAsync(T requestModel, Class<R> responseModel, String url, String postCookies)
            throws JsonProcessingException {
        ctmLogger.debugObject(ValueConstant.SHOPPING_CART_SERVICE_NAME,"REST call", url);
        HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.POST;
        Class<R> responseType = responseModel;
        ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders(postCookies);
        HttpEntity<T> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestModel, headers);
        response = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, JsonNode.class);
        ctmLogger.debugObject(ValueConstant.SHOPPING_CART_SERVICE_NAME,"response", response);
        List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get(ValueConstant.SET_COOKIE);
        ctmLogger.info("test:", cookies.toString());
        JsonNode responseBody = response.getBody();
        for (String cookie : cookies) {
            System.out.println(cookie);
            if (cookie.startsWith(((ValueConstant.TX_CART_ID)))) {
                ((ObjectNode) responseBody).put(ValueConstant.COOKIES, cookie);
            }
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        if ( response.getBody() != null) {
            System.out.println("entered here");
            return objectMapper.treeToValue(response.getBody(), responseType);
        }
        return (R) response.getBody();
    }

    private HttpHeaders getHeaders(String cartIdCookies) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, cartIdCookies);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.HOST, "www-sit-g1.dell.com");
        return headers;
    }
```

Now I am trying to write a test case for `persistGenericModelsAsync()`. The code is below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GenericRestTemplateTest {

    @InjectMocks
    GenericRestTemplate genericRestTemplate;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    CartRequest request;

    @Mock
    HttpEntity<CartRequest> requestEntity;

    @Mock
    ResponseEntity<JsonNode> response;

    @Mock
    HttpHeaders headers;

    @Mock
    List<String> cookies;

    @Mock
    JsonNode responseBody;

    @Mock
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Mock
    CartResponse cartResponse;

    @Mock
    CtmLogger ctmLogger;

    @Mock
    JsonNode jsonNode; 

    @Mock
    ObjectNode objectNode;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        cookies = Arrays.asList("TxCartIdtest", "test");

    }

    @Test
    public void persistGenericModelsAsync() throws JsonProcessingException {

        when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST), Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Mockito.eq(JsonNode.class))).thenReturn(response);
        when(response.getHeaders()).thenReturn(headers);
        List<String> cookiesTest = Arrays.asList("TxCartIdtest", "test");
        when(headers.get(ValueConstant.SET_COOKIE)).thenReturn(cookiesTest);
        when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(jsonNode);
    }
```

The stack trace for the error is :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnnecessaryStubbingException:

Unnecessary stubbings detected in test class: GenericRestTemplateTest
Clean & maintainable test code requires zero unnecessary code.
Following stubbings are unnecessary (click to navigate to relevant line of code):
  1. -> at com.dell.ctm.cart.util.GenericRestTemplateTest.persistGenericModelsAsync(GenericRestTemplateTest.java:81)
  2. -> at com.dell.ctm.cart.util.GenericRestTemplateTest.persistGenericModelsAsync(GenericRestTemplateTest.java:82)
  3. -> at com.dell.ctm.cart.util.GenericRestTemplateTest.persistGenericModelsAsync(GenericRestTemplateTest.java:84)
  4. -> at com.dell.ctm.cart.util.GenericRestTemplateTest.persistGenericModelsAsync(GenericRestTemplateTest.java:85)
Please remove unnecessary stubbings or use 'lenient' strictness. More info: javadoc for UnnecessaryStubbingException class.
```

I am trying to mock a list of cookies and trying to see if the method is executing and covering all the statements within it. But it is throwing this Unnecessary Stubbing Exception. Where have I stubbed unnecessarily?

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Have you noticed that you haven't called the method you are testing in your test case? In that case all of your mock stubs are rendered unnecessary

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@Test
public void persistGenericModelsAsync() throws JsonProcessingException {

    //stubbed - but never used
    when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST), Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Mockito.eq(JsonNode.class))).thenReturn(response);

    //stubbed - but never used
    when(response.getHeaders()).thenReturn(headers);
    List<String> cookiesTest = Arrays.asList("TxCartIdtest", "test");
    //stubbed - but never used
    when(headers.get(ValueConstant.SET_COOKIE)).thenReturn(cookiesTest);
    //stubbed - but never used
    when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(jsonNode);
}
```

Its clear that, none of the stubs you created with `when()` is getting used any where. 
For Eg. , the first stub where you return a response object - you have never used a call to `restTemplate.exchange()` any where in test execution of this method.

When you use the `strict` stubbing mode, you need to make sure - you use any stub that you create. See [more here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.6/org/mockito/exceptions/misusing/UnnecessaryStubbingException.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have this kind of error when you try to mock something which is never called during the process or when you try to mock it with some parameters that are not the same as the parameters actually filled in.